# How to get the value of text from text boxes using Java Script

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a requirement where text boxes, which are generated dynamically, display some data on the screen.
The text boxes are editable and if users want to change the content, they can put the enter new data and push it on the server.
I tried sending the data using Forms, however, it is not working, so have to resort to Java Script by capturing the data on client side and then pushing it to the server.

The problem that I'm facing is that the text boxes are generated dynamically and have same ids and tag names.
I'm able to find the count of the text boxes, however not able to find the value of the text boxes. Can some one please help.

My HTML code is

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $fieldName[] = $row['fieldName'];
    $fieldText[] = $row['fieldText'];
    $fieldID[]   = $row['ID'];

    if ($_GET['showname']){                                 
        echo"<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['fieldName']."</td>";
        echo '<td>'.'<input type = "text" class="form-control" disabled = "disabled" id ="fieldText" name = "fieldText['.$row["ID"].']" value = "'.$row["fieldText"].'">'."</td>";
        //echo "<td>".$row['fieldText']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

On submit button, I'm calling the Update function that will capture the run time values in the text boxes:

```
function updateVal()
{
    var node_list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var c=0;
    for (var i = 0; i < node_list.length; i++) {
        var node = node_list[i];
        if (node.getAttribute('type') == 'text')
        {

        //Not sure how to extract the value from Text boxes and create a json
         c++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `var value=node.value;` that's it..

Comment: You should use
`var content = this.value;`

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao Thank you for the code. however, it is just giving me the value of the first node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created three arrays as below.

```
 var fieldName = [];
 var fieldText = []
 var ID = [];
```

And constructed a json object `postData` and stringified the same.

Sample :

```js
function updateVal() {
    var node_list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var c = 0;
    var fieldName = [];
    var fieldText = []
    var ID = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < node_list.length; i++) {
        var node = node_list[i];
        if (node.getAttribute('type') == 'text') {
            fieldName[c] = node.name;
            fieldText[c] = node.value;
            ID[c] = node.id;
            c++;
        }
    }
    var postData = {
        fieldName: fieldName,
        fieldText: fieldText,
        ID: ID
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(postData));
}

updateVal();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" value="text1value" />
<input type="text" id="text2" name="text2" />
<input type="text" id="text3" name="text3" />
<input type="text" id="text4" name="text4" value="text4value" />
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/8mo7efvt/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var capturedValues = {};
```

Then in your forloop do:

```
capturedValues[node.name] = node.value;
```

Finally convert object to JSON string:

```
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(capturedValues);
```

Comment: This is giving me the value of the last text box, not all the text boxes

Comment: Name your input elements differently a else just push the input value to an array. Ex. `myArray.push(node.value)'

Comment: My inputs ids were same, but have made it different now by adding the unique row ids. But it still not working.. :(

Comment: From elements are generally identified by names not ids. Set name attribute to input elements and it should work. `Ex: <input name='input1'>`

Comment: Names were different and unique only.: ids were same, so I changed the id to make it unique

Comment: Possible to provide an example at JS fiddle pls

Comment: Thanks Simon, I'm able to get the solution. Your solution also worked. Its great to see community working. Would definitely like to give back one day.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <input type="text" id="myText" value="">
   <p id="out"></p>
   <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <script>
         function myFunction() {
           var txt= document.getElementById("myText").value;
           document.getElementById("out").innerHTML=txt;}
    </script>
```